# Capturing Network Router Traffic with Wireshark

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark

i want to see whole router traffic network.

```
How i can do this with wireshark? :)
```

I can see my Wireless network card:
[List of Adapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi0Eb.png)

but i want see my Router network traffic.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your router model (I assume you have a standard home ISP router), you should be able to mirror your Router's traffic into a particular LAN port on the device. This will act as a sort of "LAN-TAP", and will mirror all traffic flowing through the Router to that port.

[Here](https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/2017/08/setting-up-router-traffic-mirroring-to-wireshark/) is an article explaining it.

However, you should ask yourself whether or not this is particularly necessary.

Most home routers are realisticaly, just a switch that acts as a PAT Router for your ISP. You can't do any funky routing on your own LAN with them, so this router is just sitting back and forwarding packets that are travelling over the LAN. This means that due to your home router broadcasting packets from devices on the network, the packets are naturally going to be hitting your network adapter too, which will be visible on Wireshark.

However, if you are wanting to be viewing packets that are being routed by your Router to *Outside* the network, go ahead and enable port mirroring.

Comment: hey bro, its parent control.. I want see what my childs are doing in network without doing something on their devices.

Comment: I see, I think you may be going about this the wrong way - Wireshark is great for packet analysis ect but isn't exactly user friendly if its sole purpose is to monitor what the devices are doing on the network. For example, what are you really going to achieve by analysing your child's HTTP GET packet?

I would reccommend installing and using the free version of something like PRTG Network Monitor. It has a lovely GUI and should show you if devices on the network are reaching out to dodgy websites ect. Other than that, I think trust is the best LAN monitoring service.

Comment: i have to do this with wireshark. i am programmer so its for me not hard to read packets